# AngularJS directive multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I want to make my directive multiple selectors.

My directive is alerting every tap.

I already wrote this code:

```
angular
    .module('app.directives')
    .directive('onTap', someDirective)
    .directive('button', someDirective);

someDirective.$inject = ['$ionicGesture'];

function someDirective($ionicGesture) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: link
    };

    function link($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
        $ionicGesture.on('tap', function() {
            alert('Tapped!');
        }, $elem);
    }
}
```

This code problem is this button for example:

```
<button on-tap="doSomething()">Do something</button>
```

Because this button tap will alert twice!

I can even solve if i change the directive:

```
.directive('someDirective', someDirective);
```

But it means  I have to add it to every `button` or `[onTap]` selector.

Any good solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function someDirective($ionicGesture) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link($scope, $elem, $attrs, ctrls) {
        if (directive.name === 'onTap' && $elem.is('button')) {
            return;
        }

        $ionicGesture.on('tap', function() {
            alert('Tapped!');
        }, $elem);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not what i meant. I meant that I want to make a list of selectors that will exec alert function at tap. And if the element is more than 1 selector at my list (button, [onTap]) so the alert will exec only 1 time and not twice.